# Appwrite Function not receiving payload when triggered with API call

Tags: appwrite

I have created an Function in my Appwrite project. The function is not receiving the payload I attempt to give it through an HTTP-Post request (Postman). I have created a function which takes ONE property as an example to illustrate the problem.

The output of the function is as follows when called:

[image]

As you can see the payload is empty. The call looks like this:

[image]

As you can see I am giving it a payload. The code of the function is this:

```
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
  const client = new sdk.Client();

  try{

    client
        .setEndpoint(req.variables['APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT'])
        .setProject(req.variables['APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID'])
        .setKey(req.variables['APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY'])
        .setSelfSigned(true);

    // Detect if Payload is present
    if(!req.payload){
      res.json({"error": "no payload", "payload": req.payload}, 400)
    }

    // Read in payload
    const payload = JSON.parse(req.payload)

    // Check if all requested payload methods are present
    if(!payload.maxNumber) {
      res.json({success: false, message: "Invalid payload."}, 400);
      return;
    }
    // Create random number (Yes I know this won't work because the Payload is a string, but this is just an example and I'm trying to at least get the payload to be detected :-)
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * payload.maxNumber);

    // Send result
    res.send({success:true, number: randomNumber})

  }catch(e){
    res.json({success: false, message: "Unexpected error: " + e, payload: req.payload}, 400);
  }
};
```

I've been attempting to solve this issue for a few hours now. I hope someone is able to assist in this, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're passing the payload to the API correctly. According to the [docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/client/functions?sdk=rest-default#functionsCreateExecution), the payload should be passed in via the `data` parameter and it should be a string. Here's an example HTTP request from the docs:

```http
POST /v1/functions/{functionId}/executions HTTP/1.1
Host: HOSTNAME
Content-Type: application/json
X-Appwrite-Response-Format: 1.0.0
X-Appwrite-Project: 5df5acd0d48c2
X-Appwrite-JWT: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ...

{
  "data": "[DATA]",
  "async": false
}
```